# Can GitHub add source and destination branches into title?

Tags: github

In order to keep PRs easy to identify I always add source and destination branch names into PR title, e.g. `[main < add-new-ui-components] Add Submit and Reset buttons to Contact form`.

I enter destination and source branch names manually. Is there a way to have GitHub automatically add them to the title? I'm thanking similar to the way that templates for issues work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1, with a script file and API

You can achieve this with the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request).

Example code, do not copy directly without the required changes:

```js
// Octokit.js
// https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'YOUR-TOKEN'
})

await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls', {
  owner: 'OWNER',
  repo: 'REPO',
  title: 'Amazing new feature',
  body: 'Please pull these awesome changes in!',
  head: 'octocat:new-feature',
  base: 'master',
  headers: {
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
  }
})
```

Put the script in a file that you can run every time you want to create a PR :). This might be a bit tedious, but it works

### Solution 2, with GitHub Actions

Use this [GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pull-request-updater-github-action), and with an example `yaml` -file:

```yaml
name: "Update Pull Request"
on: pull_request

jobs:
  update_pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: tzkhan/pr-update-action@v2
      with:
        repo-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        base-branch-regex: '[a-z\d-_.\\/]+'
        head-branch-regex: 'foo-\d+'
        title-template: '[%basebranch% > %headbranch%] '
        body-template: |
          Merging into '%basebranch%'
          [Link to %headbranch%](https://url/to/browse/ticket/%headbranch%)
        body-update-action: 'suffix'
        body-uppercase-base-match: false
```

This action is activated when every PR is created, updates the title and body of a PR. The given `title` and `body`-template is prefixed to the original `title` and `body` of the PR.

**NOTE** Just remember to update `base-branch-regex` and `head-branch-regex`